# Laravel Eloquent - Working with an array of JSON objects

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, object, eloquent

I have an array of JSON objects within my database (as depicted by the image below)

[image]

How do I search for a specific value within it? Say I want the record where the "ends_at" field is equal to "2018-11-24 08:00:00"

I've tried using

`->where('column->starts_at', '2018-11-24 08:00:00')`

or even tried

`->whereJsonContains('column->starts_at', '2018-11-24 08:00:00').`

Within the model I've cast the column to an array - am I missing something, or can this not be done?

Comment: May be you can try this :
`DB::table('your_table')->whereRaw('json_contains(column, \'["value"]\')')->get();`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this:

```php
->whereJsonContains('column', ['starts_at' => '2018-11-24 08:00:00'])
```

Comment: @HelenChe Do you mean `->where('column->starts_at', '2018-11-24 08:00:00')`?

Comment: Sorry I meant `<`, `>` and such. I took a quick look at the Builder code but I'm not seeing any options for this...

Comment: Do you mean `->where('foo->bar', '<', 123)`?

Comment: Yes... but that is only if `foo->bar` is simply key-value from my understanding. Apologies if I'm not making sense but let's try the original question posted as example: how would I get results of the JSON array where `availability > 9`?

Comment: I've tried `->whereJsonContains('column', ['availability', '>', 9])` will not work unfortunately.

Comment: Now I see what you mean. I'm pretty sure a query like this is not possible.