# How to search/ update an array of json object as the one below using Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Sample Data

```
[{
    "name": "aml_kyc",
    "order": 4,
    "online": true,
    "enabled": true,
    "completed": false
}, {
    "name": "payment_video",
    "order": 6,
    "online": false,
    "enabled": true,
    "completed": false
}]
```

I tried `$project->where('project_progress->name', 'aml_kyc')->first()` but I get `null`

`Laravel@latest`
`MySQL@5.7.27`

Comment: can u post your table structure.

Comment: How will that help?

Comment: are u putting this data in a json field?

Comment: Of course I am.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Eloquent - Working with an array of JSON objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53007520/laravel-eloquent-working-with-an-array-of-json-objects)

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work. Maybe because Im on `5.7.27` ver

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Shows null in result

Comment: How are you using `whereJsonContains()`?

Comment: The same way the link above uses it.

Comment: Can you post it?

Answer (score 0):

Because your condition query is wrong, and your **json is nested by array**.

Try to use **JSON_CONTAINS**

```php
 $project->whereRaw('json_contains(project_progress, ?)', ['{"name":"aml_kyc"}'])->first()
```

Comment: Still returning null.

Comment: The column name is `project_progress`. It is a JSON column.

Comment: Still the same. `null`

Comment: Now it returns the whole data, as in, the entire row in the database.

Comment: @AliGajani json_contains only return the row that `project_progress` contains `{"name":"aml_kyc"}`

Comment: @AliGajani I have test it, it works to me, can u provide `$project->whereRaw('json_contains(project_progress, ?)', ['{"name":"aml_kyc"}'])->toSql()`?

Comment: `select * from `projects` where json_contains(project_progress, ?)`

Comment: @AliGajani It seems no problem with it. Are those rows all contains `{"name":"aml_kyc"}`?

Comment: There are 8 but it should work even with 2, in the sample.

Answer (score -1):

```
protected $casts = [
    'project_progress' => 'array',
];
```

Comment: I want to be able to query and update some values though. PS: I am already doing casting.

Comment: can you try with ```whereJsonContains``` instead of ```where```? what is your mySQL version?

Comment: My MySQL version is `5.7.27`