# Using whereJsonContains and compare parameter to an array of strings

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent

I've asked this in Laracasts but I have yet to receive an answer to this question. I have seen this stackoverflow post: [Laravel Eloquent - Working with an array of JSON objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53007520/laravel-eloquent-working-with-an-array-of-json-objects)

Simply put, I would like to know if there is a way for me to use:

> ->whereJsonContains('column', ['starts_at' => '2018-11-24 08:00:00'])

but instead of just one value, I'd like to compare it to an array of values, i.e:

> $dates = ['2018-11-24 08:00:00', '2020-19-01 08:00:00'];
>
> ->whereJsonContains('column', ['starts_at' => $dates])

I am fully aware that this does not work because whereJsonContains only supports comparing one value instead of an array, so I figured I needed to combine this with the method whereIn. However, I am unable to accomplish this.

Any help will be fully appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use multiple `orWhereJsonContains()` constraints:

```php
$query->where(function ($query) use ($dates) {
   foreach ($dates as $date) {
       $query->orWhereJsonContains('column', ['starts_at' => $date]);
   }
});
```