# Laravel 8 json colum where with array of object

Tags: laravel

I would like to perform a query in a table where the column is of json type and it contains array of objects, but only if a certain condition is met

This is my current code

```
$initial_results = DB::table('toys')->select('id','name')->where(['name' => 'sammy', 'email' => 'whateveremail']);
if($sk ==='yes') {
      $results = $initial_results->>whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(`info`,\'{"sku":"B07V3SSLN11"}\')')
       >whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(`info`,\'{"asin":"DTI-LALF3-EA18"}\')')
      ->get();
} else {
    $results = $initial_results->get();
}
```

But I always get 0 result if the condition is met. In database, the info I want to query indeed exist. What is the proper  way to query a json column which contains array of objects? See my example data

```
  [
   {
    "sku": "DTI-LALF3-EA18",
    "adId": 244077676726655,
    "asin": "B07V3SSLN11",
    "cost": 0,
},
{
    "sku": "DTI-LALF3-EA18",
    "adId": 242968940906362,
    "asin": "B07V3SSLN11",
    "cost": 10,
   .........
   ................
```

I even tried

```
    $initial_results = DB::table('toys')->select('id','name')->where(['name' => 'sammy', 'email' => 'whateveremail'])->->whereIn(DB::raw("JSON_EXTRACT(info, '$[*].asin')"),['B07V3SSLN11']);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it matter that your example data has a space between the colon and the quotation mark, but your SQL does not? Because it's a string search, so it has to be exact, no?

Comment: @James, same result if I add space

Comment: What about if you remove the { and }..... JSON_CONTAINS('info',\'"sku":"B07V3SSLN11"\')

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53007520/laravel-eloquent-working-with-an-array-of-json-objects/53017858?

Comment: @Rwd. No. Maybe the reason its not working because I have multiple where conditions ->whereJsonContains('info', ['asin' => 'B07V3SSLN11'])
                ->whereJsonContains('info', ['sku' => 'DT-LALF3-EA18'])

Answer (score 1):

You can query `JSON` columns by using the `->` operator in your clause:

```
->where('info->asin', 'DTI-LALF3-EA18')
```

[JSON Where Clauses Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#json-where-clauses)

Comment: It doenst work for a json colum whose data is array of objects